# Library as dependency for another library

Tags: c++, dependencies, shared-libraries

I have a big project compiled into libProject.so-file (shared library), I made some modules (shared libraries too) which use code from all libProject. Can I set libProject as dependence for moduleProject.so file? (gcc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just link with it like any other library

```
gcc -L/path/to/lib -lProject -o moduleProject.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.